# Проблема с почтой после переезда сайта

Tags: php, yii2, yii, smtp, email

После переезда на новый сервер перестала отправляться почта.

Все письма находятся в статусе "Wait". 
http://prntscr.com/nuai2y

Сайт сделан на Yii. Почта отправляется по SMTP. Используемые настройки:

```
 'postman' => [
           'class'          => 'rmrevin\yii\postman\Component',
           'driver'         => 'smtp',
           'default_from'   => ['no-replay@email.com'],
           'subject_prefix' => null,
           'subject_suffix' => null,
           'table'          => '{{%postman_letter}}',
           'view_path'      => '/email',
'smtp_config'    => [
               'host'     => 'smtp.office.com',
               'port'     => ****,
               'auth'     => true,
               'user'     => 'no-reply@email.com',
               'password' => '*********',
               'secure'   => '@@@@',
               'debug'    => false,
           ],
       ]
```

Как исправить? Все прекрасно работало на старом сервере.

Comment: Логично же, что надо сервак настроить. Попробуй отправить что-то из консоли и посмотри логи почтового сервера.

Comment: 1. Убедитесь, что письмо точно отправляются через smtp. 2. Может быть они все таки уходят, а проблема на стороне интерфейса (тот что на скрине) 3. Может быть в настройках почты есть какие-нибудь локальные адреса, которые работали на старом сервере, а на этом нет.

Answer (score 0):

Постфикс советую проверить на хосте, может быть в нем проблема, 10 раз нарывался из-за проблем с постфикс

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Внести изменения вы можете кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1008132/edit).